# Login and change div section to "welcome $username"

Tags: ajax, login-script

I am using div to display username/password/submit

Also using AJAX to inform "login invalid" without refreshing page

What I need to do is,

If login success, hide the elements of div section that used to log in, then display "welcome $username" in the same div.

(Without any page reloading)

Could anybody help me please?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? That would make this question more easy to answer;)

Comment: No, I am using AJAX, if I am not ignorant of these 2 terms

Comment: AJAX is a technology which jQuery utilises in some of its functions. Are you using a javascript library at all to handle AJAX stuff or are you just using plane javascript?

Comment: I am using library , some thing like ajaxObj.open("POST",file, true);

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `post` method:

```
$.post(
    '/url/to/post/login/details/to/',
    $('#login-form').serilaize(),
    function(data) {
        // hide the existing div and add a paragraph containing the data
        // returned form the server
        $('#some-div')
            .hide()
            .after('<p>' + data + '</p>');
});
```

assuming that `data` just contains the logged in users username.

Comment: I am using AJAX stuff, like this ajaxObj.open("POST",file, true); So is it possible to do it with AJAX or should I use jQuery post method, as you said?

Comment: Well it looks like you are using some other library which will send an AJAX request for you. The jQuery `$.post()` function sends an AJAX request in the same way using the POST HTTP request method. Either way you are doing the same thing, but jQueries AJAX functions are very easy to use.